# In vim, how to map "command-right" and "command-left" to beginning of line and end of line on mac?

Tags: vim, macintosh

I'm trying to get it to be like default text editing in Mac.  I tried
`map! <D-Left> 0`
and
`map! <D-Right> $`
in ~/.vimrc, but of course it didn't work.  How can i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, the Command key modifier syntax ([`<D-...>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#%3CD-)) is only effective in GUI-mode instances of *Vim* on Mac OS X.

The *Vim* instance must be GUI-based because most terminal emulators (*Terminal*, *iTerm*, etc.) do not generate control sequences for Command key combinations, so a tty-only instance of *Vim* has no way to know that a Command key combination was ever pressed (the terminal emulator never sends anything across the tty interface). In fact, *Terminal* binds ⌘← and ⌘→ (Command-Left and -Right) to cycling through its open windows, so those keys are “already taken” when you are typing in the context of *Terminal*.

[*MacVim*](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) (when run in GUI mode) does come with functional mappings for (among other Mac-style keystrokes) `<D-Left>` and `<D-Right>` (respectively, to [`<Home>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%3CHome%3E) (nearly identical to `0`) and [`<End>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%3CEnd%3E) (identical to `$`)). One caveat is that these default mappings are established in `$VIM/gvimrc`, so they can only be properly overridden from your `~/.gvimrc`<sup>†</sup>.

I think there have been other GUI-based versions of *Vim* for Mac OS X, but *MacVim* seems like the only modern one.

<sup>†</sup> Roughly, the startup files are processed in this order: `$VIM/vimrc`, `~/.vimrc`, `$VIM/gvimrc`, `~/.gvimrc`. Since *MacVim*’s `$VIM/gvimrc` maps `<D-Left>`, you need to put your mapping of `<D-Left>` (if you actually want to override it) in your `~/.gvimrc` so that it has the “final say”.

Comment: thanks.  i tried iTerm 2, it worked with that, but still...what a pain...welcome back into my life, Xcode